# sc.exe using variable parameters

Tags: powershell, sc.exe

This is a bit of an odd one, but I am trying to figure out how to use sc.exe with variable parameters.  Powershell 7.X does not support Set-Service password changes for remote services.  However, you can still do so via `sc.exe <server> <servicename> obj= "domain\username" password= "whatever"`.

I am working this into an interactive script, so the remote server, service name, and username will already be in Powershell parameters.  However, doing something such as `sc.exe \\$server $service obj= "$domain\$username" password= "whatever"` does not work.  It fails with an unrecognized command error.

I assume this can be done and I am just missing something easy, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're missing the command name, `create` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-create

Comment: I am not creating the service though.  It already exists.  I am just changing the password.

Comment: Then I assume you need the [`config`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-config) subcommand.